# I have multiple diagrams in .edmx files, when I write below lambda expression I get compile time error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I have a .edmx class which has multiple diagram. when I write below lambda expression I get compile time error. I am confused to understand what is the actual problem is it my design of .edmx file or my lambda expression? I tried with normal Linq query as well but resulted in same error

lambda expression:

```
var list = context.getsdetails(cityname: "", cityid: id, stateid: StateId, catsubcatid: SellerByCatId,
                   visitcount: Convert.ToInt32(TempData["visitcount"].ToString()))
                   .Select(m => new LoadHomeMisddleModel
                   {
                       srid = m.srid,
                       logo = m.Logoimg,
                       categoryname = m.CatOrSubCatName,
                       skin = m.Skinimg,
                       title = m.title,
                       State = m.statename,
                       City = m.cityname,
                       Street = m.street
                   }).ToList();
```

I get below error message :

**'int' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov I am calling Select method after my getDetails() method is closed  some thing this way : getDetails().Select(....

Comment: yeah, my bad. I suppose `getsDetails` is stored procedure? What it returns in DB and what result type in `getsdetails` method? Based from the error result type is int. But what result type should be?

Comment: yes you are right getsDetails is a SP. return type I am expecting as var. I hope that should not matter when I am expecting var.

Comment: `var` is just syntax sugar that will be replaced to real type by compiler. Maybe you have `SELECT 1` in your stored procedure, so EF may map it to int. Based on the error - currently your procedure returns int. What if you executes it manually from SQL? What it will return?

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov it returns me set of rows with 5 columns.

Comment: What is the value of `list` if you remove the `.Select(..)` and `.ToList()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I don't get extension methods available?